# How do I use Sweet Alert Messages in Laravel 5.2 by Ajax?

Tags: ajax, laravel, laravel-5

I want after the user clicked, Without refresh page, add this product in the basket of goods then show Sweet Alert Messages for the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to create on click function and then call ajax request with done or success function.

**Example:**

```
$('.element').on('click', function() {
    $.ajax({
       method:"method",
       url: url,
       data: {
           ..
       }
    })
    .done(function() {
       //other stuff
       swal('Title','Text','success');
    });
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you so much, this code is: $('#addCompare').on('click', function() {
  var valAdd = $('#addCompare').val();
  $.ajax({
   method:"GET",
   url: addCompare,
   data: {
     'hotel_id' : valAdd,
  }
 })
  .done(function() {
   //other stuff
   swal('Title','Text','success');
  });
 });

Comment: Where is my problem?

Comment: Your problem occurs in data section. You cannot pass data as a text. So you need to change `'hotel_id': valAdd` to `hotel_id: valAdd`,

Comment: but is url is: http://localhost:8000/[object%20HTMLCollection]?hotel_id=1 this correct is: http://localhost:8000/addCompare?hotel_id=1, where is my problem?

Comment: Have you set addCompare var in the end of your view file? Like: `<script type="text/javascript">
  var addCompare = '{{route('addCompare')}}';
</script>`